# How tall are the Seven + Reyna and Nico in Heroes of Olympus?

Tags: percy-jackson, the-heroes-of-olympus

So, I was rereading the Heroes of Olympus series and I started wondering how tall everyone was in comparison for each other. I decided to draw a picture of the seven (plus Nico and Reyna) later on, and so I ended up needing this information. I  If you can provide estimates of each character's height that'd be great. Comparison excerpts (from Heroes of Olympus, Magnus Chase, or Trials of Apollo) would also be a great help. It might also help to show age so I can figure out proportions.

Comment: i would guess the height of gods is not fixed -- zeus can assume any form he wants.

Comment: Why does the height of the gods matter? I mean Percy Jackson, Annabeth Chase, Jason Grace, Piper McLean, Leo Valdez, Frank Zhang, Hazel Levesque, Nico di Angelo, and Reyna Avila Ramirez-Arellano. Were you trying to find it through use of genetics? That wouldn't work, as gods don't have DNA, they have ichor. The production of the child is a miracle in itself.

Comment: _The Demigod Diaries_ and _The Demigod Files_ are two ancillary books with short stories and, more importantly here, illustrations of main characters.  Could be helpful in finding relative height, at least.

Comment: Eshier, I checked those... not much help. The illustrations of the characters are either no longer canon or aren't helpful due to the characters not being side by side.